# IceCube/Ruby A rule for every 1 month and 10 days

Tags: ruby, ice-cube

Is it possible to make a rule like every 1 month and 10 days? Obviously 40 days isn't correct since months have a variable number of days in them, and it isn't by day of month or a particular day of the week?

Something that would generate:

```
1/01/2014
2/10/2014
3/20/2014
4/30/2014
6/09/2014
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since IceCube's goal is to be iCal compliant, and that type of recurrence rule is not supported by the iCal spec as far as I can tell, this type of rule is impossible with IceCube.

Had to roll my own system.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so familiar with ice_cube, but just by checking out the README I think this could work:

```
schedule.add_recurrence_rule Rule.monthly.day_of_month(10)
```

Comment: That would return 1/10/2014, 2/10/2014, which is not what Greg Olsen wants.

Comment: Thanks Tamer, but like I said, its not the 10th day of every month, which the above rule gives but 1 month and 10 days.